# Disable button in a Listview's row while getting response of a save?

Tags: android, sqlite, button, notifydatasetchanged

**Issue:**
I have a Listview in Mainactivity. Each row of listview has two buttons say SET and RUN.
Pressing SET will take you to SET activity and if the user clicks save button in SET Activity, I need to disable the SET button in the corresponding row position of the listview in mainactivity.

**So Far Done:**
For that I have a refresh function on a onclicklistener to requery the list with updated values. How to call that refresh function without keypress in the Mainactivity or is there any other way?

**Activity MAIN :**

```
 viewHolder.ButtonSET.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    String title = v.getTag().toString();

                    if (title.equals("SET")) {

                        if (Integer.parseInt((String) viewHolder.TDNQTY.getText()) > 0) {

                            if(scanoverornot(pos)<=0) {

                                Intent s = new Intent(DN.this, SETActivity.class);
                                s.putExtra("position", pos);
                                s.putExtra("mode", "SET");

                                try{

                                    startActivityForResult(s, saverequestcode);
                                    // getContext().startActivity(s);

                                 }
                                catch(Exception e){
                                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),""+e,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                           }

                        }
                    }
                }

            });
```

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (data == null)
            return;

        switch (requestCode) {

            case saverequestcode:

                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                    String SItem= data.getStringExtra("SItem");
                    int SPos= data.getIntExtra("SPos", 0);
                    saved = 700;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+ SItem+ SPos, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //btnvalidate.performClick();
                }
       }
                   
}
```

**Activity SET :**

```
  Intent sav = new Intent();
  sav.putExtra("SItem", String.valueOf(itemno));
  sav.putExtra("SPos", String.valueOf(pos));
  setResult(RESULT_OK, sav);
  finish();
```

Comment: Start your SET activity with startActivityFor Result. PutExtra the items position. When the SET activity is done finisch with position in intent. In onActivityResult you obtain position parameterfrom data intent and adapt parameter in adapter. Then call notifyDataSetChanged.

Comment: Can you explain this with a code [ In onActivityResult you obtain position parameterfrom data intent and adapt parameter in adapter. Then call notifyDataSetChanged.] ?

Comment: Could you please guide me here with edited code above?

Comment: Yes. `s.putExtra("position", pos);` Where did you determine `pos` ? You should do that in onClick(). Normally one would use the tag for position but you put the text for the button in it. Put the position in it and you do not have to check if it is the SET button as it can only be that button. Please adapt your code.

Comment: If you need to know the text of the button then use `(Button) v). getText(); `

Comment: That intentExtra `s.putExtra("position", pos); ` is receiving its elements fine on SET Activity run

Comment: The one which has issue is the intent which is sent back from SET Activity while setting setResult. Refer [ onActivityResult ] and [ Activity SET ] above

Comment: `is receiving its elements fine on SET Activity run ` I believe that. But what does pos stand for? Is it the same as the position of the item in the list? You need that position in onActivityResult in order to be able to disable the clicked button. You can of course use two putExtras for both pos and position. Please tell how alll should work as now i have to ask you all which takes so much time.

Comment: Yes Spos is assigned with value of item position which is pos

Comment: And you did not even tell if   int SPos= data.getIntExtra("SPos", 0); gives the right value. Or what would be the issue then.

Comment: You removed all that code. No tag used. No position in putExtra(). I cannot help you in this way.

Comment: That code part doesn't have any issue. Only [ onActivityResult ] and [ ActivitySET ] is where the issue is. And `SPos= data.getIntExtra("SPos", 0);` where 0 is a default value. Forget the IntExtra it is not even working with one Extra on setResult

Comment: Repeat: `And you did not even tell if int SPos= data.getIntExtra("SPos", 0); gives the right value. Or what would be the issue then`

Comment: No. That has no issue though , I solved it and posted an answer. Thank you so much, @blackapps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue Lines:**

1. Have to add `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);`
2. Removed `switch` case and used `if` condition for `requestCode` check

**Solution:**

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     
        if (data == null)
            return;

        if (requestCode == saverequestcode) {

            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                String SItem = data.getStringExtra("SItem");
                String SPos = data.getStringExtra("SPos");
                
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item :" + SItem + "Position :" + SPos, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         
            }
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                //Any methods
            }
        }
        else if (requestCode == importrequestcode){


        }
}
```

**Activity SET :**

```
  Intent sav = new Intent();
  sav.putExtra("SItem", String.valueOf(itemno));
  sav.putExtra("SPos", String.valueOf(pos));
  setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,sav);
  finish();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `startActivityForResult` to nail this purpose:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, DestinationActivity.class), MY_RESULT);
```

And then in your `MainActivity`:

```
public int MY_RESULT = 10;
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == MY_RESULT) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            //refresh the list according to your logic
        } 
    }
}
```

Don't forget to call `setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);` when user clicks save button.

```
saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
        }
    });
```